# asp.net with SQLDataSource

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, sqldatasource

i have two SqlDataSource one of them depends on a return value of the other 
how can i do this

```
<i><asp:SqlDataSource runat="server" ID="SqlDataSource2" ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:mainConnectionString %>' SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [schools]"></asp:SqlDataSource>

        <asp:SqlDataSource runat="server" ID="SqlDataSource1" ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:mainConnectionString %>' SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [School_imgs] WHERE ([School_ID] = @School_ID)">
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="School_ID" Type="Int32"></asp:Parameter>
            </SelectParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>"</i>
```

Comment: Avoid `SqlDataSource`, instead work with ADO.NET directly.

Comment: `SqlDataSource` exists for quickly putting together simple CRUD operations for simplistic applications, it does not scale and is very inflexible, as you're seeing.

Comment: Using `SqlDataSource` also means completely disregarding separation-of-concerns because you're mixing database query logic with presentation-tier view code.